# Selenium : Get a div that contains a specific div class inside it

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, findelement

I have a page structure which contains a classname assigned to multiple divs. But there is one specific div that will contain a specific div.class inside it which happens dynamically.

```
<div class="ProductVariants__VariantCard-sc-1unev4j-3 bEuNss">
   <div class="ProductVariants__RadioButtonContainer-sc-1unev4j-4 jqJIBg">
     <div class="ProductVariants__RadioButtonOuter-sc-1unev4j-5 jcgpFW">
       <div class="ProductVariants__RadioButtonInner-sc-1unev4j-6 fgFqYM">
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="ProductVariants__VariantDetailsContainer-sc-1unev4j-7 fvkqJd">
     <p class="ProductVariants__VariantUnitText-sc-1unev4j-8 bZvIga">50 g</p>
     <div class="ProductVariants__PriceContainer-sc-1unev4j-9 jjiIua">
       ₹111 
       <span class="ProductVariants__MRPText-sc-1unev4j-10 jEinXG">
         ₹345
       </span>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

If you see here this class `ProductVariants__RadioButtonInner-sc-1unev4j-6 fgFqYM` Line number 4 will be contained within one that specific class. Though there could be multiple of `ProductVariants__VariantCard-sc-1unev4j-3 bEuNss`.

How do I get the class `ProductVariants__VariantCard-sc-1unev4j-3 bEuNss` which contains `ProductVariants__RadioButtonInner-sc-1unev4j-6 fgFqYM` inside it.

This is what I have tried

```
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[contains(@class,'ProductVariants__VariantCard-sc-1unev4j-3 bEuNss')]//div[contains(@class, 'ProductVariants__RadioButtonInner-sc-1unev4j-6 fgFqYM')]")
```

But this instead gives me the inner div and not the whole outer div

```
'<div class="ProductVariants__RadioButtonInner-sc-1unev4j-6 fgFqYM"></div>'
```

Comment: XPath from code sample doesn't match XPath from Exception. Update your question

Comment: `fgFqYM` is nested at third level. So you can find this div and find parent that is three levels up. E.g. `driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('.ProductVariants__RadioButtonInner-sc-1unev4j-6.fgFqYM').parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;")`. This would break if nesting order changes.

Comment: @Firelord isn't there a more selenium way, I don't want to execute any JS

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar I don't know xpath so I suggested alternative. Although, not a really good way to do this but I can pass the whole HTML body reference from selenium to Beautifulsoup and get parent or ascendants from there using Python. No JS would be needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select ancestor node that *contain specific descendant node* try

```
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[contains(@class,'ProductVariants__VariantCard-sc-1unev4j-3 bEuNss') and .//div[contains(@class, 'ProductVariants__RadioButtonInner-sc-1unev4j-6 fgFqYM')]]")
```

Comment: `div_containing_radio = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[contains(@class,'ProductVariants__VariantCard-sc-1unev4j-3 bEuNss') and .//div[contains(@class, 'ProductVariants__RadioButtonInner-sc-1unev4j-6 fgFqYM')]]") ` 
 if I use your code and now if I try to get class `ProductVariants__PriceContainer-sc-1unev4j-9 jjiIua` inside `div_containing_radio.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="ProductVariants__PriceContainer-sc-1unev4j-9 jjiIua")` it gives error `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: `

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar you cannot pass multiple class names to search by class. Try `(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="ProductVariants__PriceContainer-sc-1unev4j-9")` or `(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=".ProductVariants__PriceContainer-sc-1unev4j-9.jjiIua")`

Answer (score 2):

To identify the `<div>` with *`class="ProductVariants__VariantCard-sc-1unev4j-3 bEuNss`* with respect to the `<div>` with *`class="ProductVariants__RadioButtonInner-sc-1unev4j-6 fgFqYM`* you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

```
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[starts-with(@class, 'ProductVariants__RadioButtonInner')]//ancestor::div[starts-with(@class, 'ProductVariants__VariantCard')]")
```

Comment: `div_containing_radio = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[contains(@class,'ProductVariants__VariantCard-sc-1unev4j-3 bEuNss') and .//div[contains(@class, 'ProductVariants__RadioButtonInner-sc-1unev4j-6 fgFqYM')]]")`  if I use your code and now if I try to get class `ProductVariants__PriceContainer-sc-1unev4j-9 jjiIua` inside `div_containing_radio.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="ProductVariants__PriceContainer-sc-1unev4j-9 jjiIua")` it gives error selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar I haven't suggested `//div[contains(@class,'ProductVariants__VariantCard-sc-1unev4j-3 bEuNss') and .//div[contains(@class, 'ProductVariants__RadioButtonInner-sc-1unev4j-6 fgFqYM')]]` within my answer.

Comment: This is just a add on, do you want me to ask another question for it?

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar Ofcoarse the locators are supposed to be different.

Comment: `div_containing_radio.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=".ProductVariants__PriceContainer-sc-1unev4j-9.jjiIua").text` this worked perfect

Comment: Can you help here please  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72874278/selenium-get-text-inside-an-element-but-not-inside-the-nested-tags-within-it