# Selenium : Get text inside an element but not texts inside the nested tags within it

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

Lets say I have an element

```
<div class="ProductVariants__PriceContainer-sc-1unev4j-9 jjiIua">
    ₹199 
    <span class="ProductVariants__MRPText-sc-1unev4j-10 jEinXG">
        ₹690
    </span>
    <div class="Product__Dicount">
        No discount available for this product
    </div>
</div>
```

When I am fetching the element by classname

```
div_containing_radio = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[starts-with(@class, 'ProductVariants__RadioButtonInner')]//ancestor::div[starts-with(@class, 'ProductVariants__VariantCard')]")
div_containing_radio.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=".ProductVariants__PriceContainer-sc-1unev4j-9.jjiIua").text
```

This gives me

```
'₹199 ₹690 No discount available for this product'
```

What I wanted was just `₹199`.

Note that I can't just format the text and get the first text on split by `space` as the structure of the page keeps changing.

Comment: For the given HTML I think you are getting `₹199 ₹690 No discount available for this product`

Comment: @undetected Selenium
edited there are many pages open so make some error while copy pasting, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using little bit JS:

```
js_query = """
            var x = document.querySelector('.ProductVariants__PriceContainer-sc-1unev4j-9.jjiIua').childNodes;
            var l = "";
    
            x.forEach(i => {
                if (i.nodeName === '#text') {
                    l += ' ' + i.textContent;
                }
            });
            return l;
"""

price = driver.execute_script(js_query).strip()
print(price)
```

Output:

```
₹199
```

What we are doing with JS is we are fetching all the child nodes of our target div element. Then we are iterating through all of these nodes and getting `textContent` values from **text** nodes only. Simultaneously, we are adding all those values into a string type variable `l`. We return `l` from JS and strip it off of useless characters in Python. That's it.

Answer (score 2):

Answer of @Firelord (+1) can be simplified as

```
div_containing_radio = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[starts-with(@class, 'ProductVariants__RadioButtonInner')]//ancestor::div[starts-with(@class, 'ProductVariants__VariantCard')]")
price = div_containing_radio.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=".ProductVariants__PriceContainer-sc-1unev4j-9.jjiIua")

print(driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;", price).strip())
```

Comment: If it is certain that the price would *always* be the first child of the parent element, then this is actually a neat simplification of my answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

To print only *`199`* from the string `₹199 ₹690 No discount available for this product` you just need to split the entire string with respect to the **`₹`** and print the second element as follows:

```
print(div_containing_radio.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=".ProductVariants__PriceContainer-sc-1unev4j-9.jjiIua").text.split("₹")[1])
```

As an alternative you can also split the string with respect to the *`blankspace`* and print the first element as follows:

```
print(div_containing_radio.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=".ProductVariants__PriceContainer-sc-1unev4j-9.jjiIua").text.split(" ")[0])
```

Comment: No text split, suggest me a selenium way to do this

Comment: Anything wrong with `split()`?

Comment: Also did you mean `₹` instead of `$`. Its not guranteed that `₹` will always be there. That is the reason I don't want to split by ` ` or `$` or `₹`

Comment: suggest me something other than split!

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar How about spliting wrt blank space?

Comment: Nope, no splitting, there must be some selenium way using combination of js

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
div_containing_radio = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,"//div[starts-with(@class, 'ProductVariants__PriceContainer-sc-1unev4j-9 jjiIua')]/following-sibling::text()")
```